# Is there anyway to access the DotNet 4.0 Class library without downloading the entire CTP VPC

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, .net-4.0

I want to check out the new DotNet 4.0 System.Numeric namespace for a project I am working on.

The only info I can find is the CTP VPC download on microsoft connect. I do not want the entire vs2010 package, I just need the System.Numeric assembly so i can run some tests on it.

Does anyone have any ideas or maybe has the VPC and can send me the dll.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no supported way to do this via Microsoft.  The only release Microsoft has issued for 4.0 is the Vs 2010 CTP.  There is no separate download for the .Net framework or any of it's libraries.

Having the DLL alone won't do you any good.  The DLL is built against the 4.0 CLR and requires a 4.0 CLR to run.  Unless you have the CTP Image you won't have the 4.0 CLR and won't be able to run/test this DLL.

I think you're stuck with getting the VPC